# Detect file type which is uploaded to server in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-type

How can i detect file type of coming to serv file, so that it is .csv i do one method, when .xls - other...
I can do it just like filename.include(".csv")? but this is bad idea...
How can i detect filetype?

Also my code:

```
other_name = uploaded_io4.original_filename   
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads_prices', uploaded_io4.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(uploaded_io4.read)
      end
```

Comment: linux has a "file" command that you can use against (filed on the file system) to try and determine their type...

Comment: There is not a bullet-proof way. The *nix OS command `file` is relatively good but can be fooled.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) type of the upload by looking at `uploaded_io4.content_type` then decide what to do based on that.

Comment: Mime-type could be spoofed because it comes from the sender.

Comment: So does the filename. If you are concerned about reliably validating it without user spoofability, its going to be hard, but the unix `file` command is going to be your best starting point, it also can be configured to spit out a MIME type: `file --mime --brief #{file_path}`

Comment: I would use a gem which does it, such as https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic